# « Intercepter » : sens nouveau dans le contexte de la défense militaire ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Dans un [article d'aujourd'hui](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/monde/en-direct-zelensky-nomme-un-ambassadeur-en-chine-apr%C3%A8s-son-entretien-avec-xi-jinping/ar-AA1amiYw?ocid=msedgdhp&pc=U531&cvid=b51d7fc7ad614226a7b6f6a7baabe7d8&ei=42) (MS News) on trouve le verbe « intercepter » que l'on applique, comme d'habitude dans ce type d'article et de nos jours, dans le contexte de la défense aérienne, à l'opération de mettre en garde des aéronefs étrangères qui ont franchi les frontières et d'assurer qu'elles arrêtent de survoler les territoires au dessus desquels elles ne sont pas autorisées.

> 8 h 19 : trois avions militaires russes interceptés au-dessus de la Baltique, selon Berlin

Dans le contexte de la défense aérienne le verbe « intercepter » a cependant un sens unique (« s'emparer », « détruire »).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intercepter))  DÉFENSE. Empêcher (un avion, un navire ennemi) d'atteindre son objectif en s'en emparant ou en le détruisant.

Ce n'est évidemment pas les sens de cette définition dont il s'agit dans l'article ; il existe donc une certaine ambigüité puisqu'on veut dire « intercepter »  dans le sens général de « faire opposition ».

Est-ce le cas que le sens de ce verbe dans les milieux militaires aurait changé et qu'il ne signifierait plus « s'emparer » ou « abattre » ? Si oui, quel était le terme que l'on utilisait auparavant pour cette sorte d'opposition ?

S'il s'agit d'un usage ambigu, quel serait un terme qui remplacerait « intercepter » avec avantage dans cet article ?

Comment: Je sens pas nécessairement la connotation de "destruction".

Answer (score 4):

***Intercepter*** signifie simplement qu'on a agi sur quelque chose lors de son déplacement d'un point à un autre.

Que l'effet de cette action soit définitif (destruction) ou non (contrôle, renvoi, altération, etc.) ne fait pas partie du sens de ce verbe.

Dans le domaine militaire, ***intercepter*** peut être un euphémisme pour ***détruire***, comme ***neutraliser*** peut l'être pour ***abattre*** (par exemple un terroriste), mais ce n'est pas une obligation.

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas nécessairement la connotation de "destruction". On dit également "intercepter un message" et "intercepter une passe" (rugby).

Comment: Il n'est pas demandé dans la question s'il y a des connotations de destruction puisqu'il  y est  dit implicitement qu'il n'y en a aucune dans le cas d'usage dans l'article et qu'il y en a une sans aucun doute (bien que « connotation » soit un peu « faible ») d'près la définition du TLFi., ce qui suscite des questions auxquelles on pourrait avoir des réponses.